# List View customized in SharePoint Designer not correctly displayed in Web Part

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-designer, list-view

I am working with SharePoint Foundation 2010. I created a Calendar list, then created a view, "Current Events". I edited "Current Events" in SharePoint Designer 2010. Some of the changes were setting the Title to Bold. Everything looks peachy in SPD, and on the Calendar page (/Lists/Calendar/Current%20Events.aspx). However, when I add a Web Part to my home page, some of the custom changes (like the bold) don't display. However, SOME of the changes (like what columns are shown) DO display. What am I missing?

Here is the site, the calendar is on the home page: http://www.oceanview335.com/

Just to clarify, I am not talking about a ListView Web Part, I am talking about editing a regular View for a list, that can then be edited like any other View (changing sort, adding fields, etc.)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When you edit in SPD, it'll add your styles directly to that page.  If you wanted to have that same styling on multiple pages, the best thing to do would be to take your css and put it into it's own file.  Then you can reference that css file on any page and it'll style your web page accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you misunderstood my question. I do understand that when you customize a web part in SPD, it is specific to that Web Part. But I am talking about customizing a view. You are supposed to be able to edit a view in SPD, then modify it again in the browser (add columns, change sort order, etc.) just like any other view. This makes the view portable just like any other view, so you can just add it on any page. Like I said, most of the functional changes I made do appear with the view, but not the bold text. Is there some step I am missing when creating a view in SPD?

Answer (score 0):

When you start making changes to the styles of the web part in SPD on a separate page, the style changes don't get applied inline, they get appended to a content placeholder on that page with classes like Style1, Style2, etc.  The CSS styles that it generates in that separate page need to be saved into a CSS file that you reference on the desired output page or you put them all inline on the particular element.

If you don't, you'll see styling issues like you're running into when the web part is exported and imported to another web part page.

Comment: Again, I am not talking about creating a web part. What you are saying is correct, IF I was creating a web part. I am talking about customizing a VIEW in SharePoint Designer:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx

In 2010, you are supposed to be able to create a view in SharePoint Designer that then becomes available just like any other view. You can edit the LIST Web Part (NOT a data view web part) on the default.aspx page, and your custom view is just another view in the drop down.